# Prime number (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, primes, sigabrt, segmentation-fault

- This is a very famous problem on SPOJ where you need to find prime numbers in a given range so the thing is  the range lies from 1 to 1000000000.But every time i allocate an array of 1000000000 size it will give me a sigsegv error or a sigabrt error how do i overcome this problem of assigning very large values to an array
- Apart from that i am using the sieve of ertosthenes algorithm to solve the problem.I have given the code below please help me resolve the problem by telling me what i need to change in my code so i don't get a sigsegv and sigabrt error.

  ```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
      int t,j;
      long long int x,y;
      cin>>t;
      int i=0;
      while(i<t)
      {
          cin>>x>>y;
          long long int *a=new long long int[y];
          for(int k=0;k<=y;k++)
              a[k]=1;
              a[0]=0;
              a[1]=0;
          for(int k=2;k<=y;k++)
          {
              if(a[k]==1)
              {
              for(j=2;k*j<=y;j++)
                      a[k*j]=0;
              }
          }
          for(int k=x;k<=y;k++)
          {
           if(a[k]==1)
                  cout<<k;
          }
          delete []a;
          i++;
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Why are you allocating an array of long long ints and then storing 0 or 1 into them? Also, do calculate how much memory it would take to allocate the array.

Comment: You have `for(int k=0;k<=y;k++) a[k]=1;`, that is you assign the `y`th element which is out of bounds. Even if there is sufficient memory.

Comment: The Sieve is a bad algorithm. Memory expense outweighs performance.

Comment: Yup it takes up to 4gb of memory which is a huge sum of memory because of which it is giving me the error.I am using the array to keep track of the elements that need to be cancelled out hence i will require a huge array to satisfy the condition.

Comment: As @SamiKuhmonen said, you don't (and shouldn't) use `long long`s for purely binary information, it's a memory overkill. Your auxiliary variable would be well off with the smallest type available, probably `unsigned char` or something.

Comment: Are you allocate memory for all numbers or only the odd numbers?  Remember that 2 is the only even prime number.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using something similar to the Sieve of Eratosthenes. The algorithm looks like:

```
bool composite[N] := {false, ..., false}
composite[0] := true
composite[1] := true
for (i from 2 to N)
    if (not composite[i])
        for (j = 2i to N skipping by i)
            composite[j] := true
```

For ranges like [1, 10^9], a nice option to cut memory usage is to use bit masking instead of booleans. This way, you use ~128MB instead of ~1GB of memory for the sieve. Edit: I forgot to mention that `std::vector<bool>` is actually internally a `std::bitset`, so you don't actually have to do any explicit bit twiddling.

A better option in terms of memory is to use the fact that a number is composite iff it has a non-trivial factor less than or equal to its square root, and combine that with a sieve. Of course, you have to augment the sieve with a list of primes. It will be empty initially, and you must append a prime each time you find one.

1. Sieve all of the primes up to 32,000 (A little more than the square root of 1,000,000,000). The result is a sorted sequence of prime numbers.
2. For each integer k, iterate over the primes less than or equal to the square root of k. If it's divisible by one of them, it's not prime. Otherwise, if the loop terminates, it's prime. When k < 32,000, you can avoid this entirely and just use the flag set in the sieve array.

This gives you O(sqrt(N) log log sqrt(N)) complexity for the sieve, and checking if an integer k is prime takes time O(sqrt(k) / log sqrt(k)) by the Prime Number Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

> please help me resolve the problem by telling me what i need to change in my code so i don't get a sigsegv and sigabrt error.

Change:

```
long long int *a=new long long int[y];
```

to:

```
std::vector<bool> a=std::vector<bool>(y);
```

`std::vector<bool>` will allocate **1 bit** for each `0`/`1` value, instead of the **64 bits** that you are probably allocating for each.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help i did what you asked me to do but in spite of the change i am getting a sigabrt error what is the cause of that.

Comment: @navroze that sounds like a new question.  :)

Comment: @navroze did you fix the out-of-bounds error I commented about? Although I think that should give you sigsegv.

Comment: @navroze OK, I realized that `vector` probably takes care of the out-of-bounds issue.  Now: the code with `vector` runs fine for me with `t==1`, `x==y==1e9`. So what is your input, or what part of your code did you not show us?

Comment: Yup i solved the out of bound error and i used bool instead of vector  which also takes a memory size of 1 bit but now i am getting a sigabrt error